# Which Jedi/Sith has proficiency in the most combat Forms?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, jedi, sith, jedi-training

The answer [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/161235/75000) ends with this opinion of Obi-Wan Kenobi:

> "Ultimately, what we see is a true dueling master. One able to **hybridize the forms** and adjust as necessary..."

The whole answer shows that Jedi could be skilled enough in multiple Forms to be able to mix-and-match as needed. This example is based on Obi-Wan and he appears to be a good contender, but I want to know if there are other Light and Dark Side Force-users who also have high skill in multiple Forms.

**Which Jedi and which Sith have the most skill in the most combat Forms?**

Comment: The seems likely to be closed as Primarily Opinion Based.

Answer (score 3):

It is hard to give definitive answer. In Canon, all Jedi and Sith have some preferred form. For example, Palpatine was described as master of all seven forms, but in his duels we could see on screen, he mostly uses Form V Djem So and Form VII Juyo, with some elements of Form IV Ataru against Windu. Anakin/Vader started with Ataru, but later switched to Form V, alternating between its two variations Shien and Djem So. Obi-Wan was master of Form III Soresu, and sometimes used Form IV Ataru. All other masters are displayed as only using one form ( Windu Form VII with its variant Vaapad, Yoda Form IV, Darth Maul Form VII Juyo, Dooku Form II Makashi etc... ).